# How to find-out what URL and JSON is used

Tags: google-chrome, web-application, api, json

I have build an application but the framework, lihaoyi autowire (minor detail), hides its auto generated and auto maintained path structure and message structure. It is fantastic but the drawback, is it's not visible in the code.

How can I found out the path of the url and the JSON involved? Using the Chrome browser? Other tools to intercept the traffic?
Finally I have to use it for to mimic and test it with using e.g. an Advanced REST client as Postman?

[An live example, just an example, of this way of programming can be found here.](https://hands-on-scala-js.herokuapp.com/)

By coincidence I found out that the url with path for this example "https://hands-on-scala-js.herokuapp.com/ajax/list" is. And I have to post path = "../" header. Tested with Postman.

Comment: @Dave The link connects your browser to a web application. When you change the text box it will post a JSON message to the server which on his turn will send a JSON message back. (Which is processed by the JavaScript in your browser .........)

Comment: To sum up, how you can find out the complete url with path of API and the data structure of the JSON, in order to dry test it with a REST client. This specific example is web application is cross compiled from a Scala source and only an example.

Comment: You can't. You'd have to look at the documentation and/or source code of the API.